# GPU goes offline (poweroff, suspend) when idle on Debian Bullseye kernel 5.9

Tags: debian, drivers, amd-graphics

The problem is - system suspends my video cards after a short idle on it. Other system devises and modules keeps online as usual.

The system is a mining rig on Debian 5.19 kernel. When card is awaken, it resets to default values part of its parameters. And it is not very usefull. Drivers - firmware-non-free from deb repo. GPU - Radeon RX 470.

After device is offline it can be awaken by accessing /sys/class/drm/card(N)/device/*

- = any read/change will wakeup GPU.

On kernel 4.19 - there was no such behavior.

Turned off aspm(Active State Power Management) gives no result (kernel boot parameter amdgpu.aspm=0)

Will work deep on it later. For now can only figure that video devise goes totally offline. Coolers stops and card becomes "cold" on touch(even 0% GPU and MEM busy, it assumed to consume 5-10Wt and give some heat, but in this case it is neraly totalyy off).

Comment: Just for now figured that behavior can be changed by modifying settings at: ```/sys/class/drm/card(N)/device/power/autosuspend_delay_ms```. It changes time the GPU will be suspended. It was 5000ms here. So just a little idle and it is offine.

Comment: Changing ```/sys/class/drm/card(N)/device/power/control``` from AUTO to ON turns off this issue. For now my GPUs never go suspended if idle.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading Debian to testing I faced behavior of the system more common for USB devices (autosuspend on delay), but this time used for GPU.

There is `/sys/class/drm/card(N)/device/power/control`

and `/sys/class/drm/card(N)/device/power/autosuspend_delay_ms`

that are responsible for suspending GPU at idle time equal to ms from `autosuspend_delay_ms` directive.

To return to old behavior have to set `control` to `on`.

Don't figured for now how to make this change permenent. So just put this into my startup mining script. It checks all available GPU's and change autosuspend mode to `on`, if it is set as `auto`.